# WCF Library Settings not in Web.config file

Tags: wcf

I have a strange situation here. I have WCF project which uses Library , Actualy I have a .svc with the contract and all the logic is in different .DLL. One solution 2 projects

The ideea is that in the library I use the App.Config file ( actually the Settings.settings file) but when I compile the WCF and use VS publish, I can't find the settings in the web.config. The project work fine, but I do not know where the settings are stored

Does anyone know something about this ?

Comment: What do youmean " actually the Settings.settings file"? You can add wcf configuration to web

Comment: My Solution: WCF_Contract_Interface.svc and Logic.DLL WCF_Contract_Interface.svc has web.config, Logic.DLL has App.config. When I publish WCF_Contract_Interface.svc to local folder, App.config is not included in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research and tries, it looks that in this kind of situation, the Settings.settings are just embeded in the .DLL, There is no additional .configuration file. If someone else has more details about why and how, is welcome to write here, Else, I think this info it's enough for others with the same problem